# Var args block argument parsing loses 1 pointer arg

Tags: objective-c, block, variadic-functions

Have a function:

```
-(void) BlockCall:(void (^)(float a, float b, NSObject *object, NSObject *secObject, NSObject *thirdObject)) argBlock
                withObject: (NSObject *)object
                   andSObj:(NSObject *)sobject
                   andTObj:(NSObject *)tobject
{

    object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    sobject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    tobject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"First object:%@", object);
    NSLog(@"Second object:%@", sobject);
    NSLog(@"Third object:%@", tobject);
    argBlock(15 ,27, object, sobject, tobject);
}
```

And varardic block:

```
 jvalue (^voidBlock)(va_list args, ...);
  voidBlock= ^(va_list args, ...){
    va_arg(parsArgs, double);
    va_arg(parsArgs, double);
     id NSObjectArg = va_arg(parsArgs, id);
     id NSObjectArg2 = va_arg(parsArgs, id);
     id NSObjectArg3 = va_arg(parsArgs, id);
     va_end(parsArgs); 
 }
```

If i call this function with correct parameters and pass this block as parameter. I will get strange result. It will read first and second float, then it will read second passed object as first, and third passed object as second. No matter how many primitives before or if there is no primitives reading va_list will always loose first pointer type.
If i will change this block definition to accept fixed args everything will be ok, but with veridic I always loose first pointer arg

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't really make any sense. Why would you have a function (block) which both takes a `va_list` (which is an encoding of another function's varargs) and also varargs? That doesn't make sense. Also, where is `parsArgs` defined? Why is there no `va_start`? And who is calling this block? Who is passing this `va_list` and subsequent arguments?